# Not able to send string to server through socket using mysql udf

Tags: mysql, sockets, unix

On mysql shell, i am running "SELECT socketCall();" which returns 5.

I am trying to connect to unix socket server( running locally) from UDF function in mysql. the connect() function used in UDF function fails somehow, and return from there immediately.

Please help me out to find what wrong i am doing in my code. I am working on raspberry pi.

The UDF function code is as :

```
#define SOCK_PATH "/root/mysock"

longlong socketCall(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error)
{
    int s,len,n;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    char str[100] = "Hello Saggu calling from MySql";

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        return 2;  
    }
    bzero((char *) &remote, sizeof(remote));
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
        return 5;
    }

    n = send(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
    close(s);
    return n;    
}
```

And the server code is as:

```
#define SOCK_PATH "/root/mysock"
int main(void)
{
    int s, s2, t, len;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    char str[100];
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
       perror("bind");
       exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
       perror("listen");
       exit(1);
    }
    for(;;) {
        int done, n;
        printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connected.\n");
        n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);
        printf("\n  %s\n",str);      
        close(s2);
    }    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please??? I am totally stuck and could not find any solution to it anywhere.

Comment: I finally had to use the tcp/ip socket instead of unix sockets and now it worked fine. I am not sure but it seems by using mysql UDFs you need to provide some special kind of permissions to the unix socket files which I am not aware of right now.